# Images are cut when using max-width 100% and height auto

Tags: html, css

I'm new to CSS, and, as my technical expertise is not quite good, I will try to explain as simply as I can.
I have an image that uses half of the screen I'm using the below CSS code after reading a couple of articles

```html
<div class="div-block-87">
  <img src="image.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
}
```

The problem is that image is cut like below:

While when I use inspect image shown as expected, see below:

Sorry, if my description is terrible but I do not know how else to explain.

Comment: Added a demo to my answer. Please check.

Comment: If you wanna give height that fills the full screen then try giving height to 100vh .

Comment: Thank you both for help! I tried Yuriy's suggestion but this didn't solved my issue. I used different combinations just to check how it works but with no result. I then used `height: 100vh;` as Uttam suggested and image is shown as expected however i got a problem with header, went in the middle of image and image is not in the middle. I've updated the question with new picture. If you have any other suggestions to try.. Current css i use 
`img {
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100vh;
}`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [object-fit: cover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit).

If you additionally need to specify image position, use [object-position: center center](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-position).

*Please note, that these attributes are unavailable in older browsers.*

If you need to support older browsers you can use `div` tag instead of `img` and style its background (image, position, size, fitting).

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yoj2a5rb/)

Answer (score 0):

You need the container to be a grid with 2 equal columns of `1fr` each and the width and height to be 100% of the visible viewport. Then your image needs to have a `max-width` in order to fit nicely into its container without requiring more space than what the parent decides.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.div-block-87 img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="div-block-87">
   <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1625756939748-c9c745e105cf">
  </div>
  <div class="div-block-88">other block</div>
</div>
```